# How do you throttle Flow in the latest Akka (2.4.6)?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

How do you throttle Flow in the latest Akka (2.4.6) ? I'd like to throttle Http client flow to limit number of requests to 3 requests per second. I found following example online but it's for old Akka and akka-streams API changed so much that I can't figure out how to  rewrite it.

```
def throttled[T](rate: FiniteDuration): Flow[T, T] = {
  val tickSource: Source[Unit] = TickSource(rate, rate, () => ())
  val zip = Zip[T, Unit]
  val in = UndefinedSource[T]
  val out = UndefinedSink[T]
  PartialFlowGraph { implicit builder =>
    import FlowGraphImplicits._
    in ~> zip.left ~> Flow[(T, Unit)].map { case (t, _) => t } ~> out
    tickSource ~> zip.right
  }.toFlow(in, out)
}
```

Here is my best attempt so far

```
def throttleFlow[T](rate: FiniteDuration) = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val ticker = Source.tick(rate, rate, Unit)

  val zip = builder.add(Zip[T, Unit.type])
  val map = Flow[(T, Unit.type)].map { case (value, _) => value }
  val messageExtractor = builder.add(map)

  val in = Inlet[T]("Req.in")
  val out = Outlet[T]("Req.out")

  out ~> zip.in0
  ticker ~> zip.in1
  zip.out ~> messageExtractor.in

  FlowShape.of(in, messageExtractor.out)
})
```

it throws exception in my main flow though :)

```
private val queueHttp = Source.queue[(HttpRequest, (Any, Promise[(Try[HttpResponse], Any)]))](1000, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .via(throttleFlow(rate))
  .via(poolClientFlow)
  .mapAsync(4) {
    case (util.Success(resp), any) =>
      val strictFut = resp.entity.toStrict(5 seconds)
      strictFut.map(ent => (util.Success(resp.copy(entity = ent)), any))
    case other =>
      Future.successful(other)
  }
  .toMat(Sink.foreach({
    case (triedResp, (value: Any, p: Promise[(Try[HttpResponse], Any)])) =>
      p.success(triedResp -> value)
    case _ =>
      throw new RuntimeException()
  }))(Keep.left)
  .run
```

where `poolClientFlow` is `Http()(system).cachedHostConnectionPool[Any](baseDomain)`

Exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The output port [Req.out] is not part of the underlying graph.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219)
    at akka.stream.impl.StreamLayout$Module$class.wire(StreamLayout.scala:204)
```

Comment: The above is pretty easy to redo in new akka streams. But it also seems flawed to me. Zip requires one from each source. A better approach might be to merge the requests and the ticks, and then have a stateful BidiFlow that answers requests with a 503 if there are more requests than ticks.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn Could you please show your version ? I've updated question with my non-working version. I don't want requests to fail. I want them to be queued and wait using backpressure.

Comment: A throttle method ?

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.6/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@throttle(cost:Int,per:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maximumBurst:Int,costCalculation:Out=>Int,mode:akka.stream.ThrottleMode):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]

Comment: @Qingwei , the problem is that expert apparently wants to throttle globally (over multiple materializations of a flow), so throttle won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt that uses the throttle method as mentioned by @Qingwei. The key is to not use `bindAndHandle()`, but to use `bind()` and throttle the flow of incoming connections before handling them. The code is taken from the [implementation of `bindAndHandle()`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/0e11ec20570f7f6bc79151cf92b7e5d710ff1234/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/Http.scala#L112), but leaves out some error handling for simplicity. Please don't do that in production.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
import system.dispatcher
val maxConcurrentConnections = 4

val handler: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, NotUsed] = complete(LocalDateTime.now().toString)

def handleOneConnection(incomingConnection: IncomingConnection): Future[Done] =
  incomingConnection.flow
        .watchTermination()(Keep.right)
        .joinMat(handler)(Keep.left)
        .run()

Http().bind("127.0.0.1", 8080)
  .throttle(3, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
  .mapAsyncUnordered(maxConcurrentConnections)(handleOneConnection)
  .to(Sink.ignore)
  .run()
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how in general I can create `FlowShape` ? How do I get connected inlet and outlet inside when I ingest given flow using `.via` ?

Comment: Sure, if I have time. But that would best be handled in another question.

Comment: @expert 's question is to limit request number to 3 per second. but this answer gives way of limit the connection number to 3. not the case.
as multiple request can arrive through same one connection, but the handlerFlow didn't throttle it.