# How to handle streaming data that comes from WSClient in Akka Stream 2

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

how to return concurrent.Future in the below code:

```
val nextMeetup = ws.url(url).stream()
        .flatMap( response => response.body
          .via(framing)
          .map(_.utf8String)
          .map(_ + "\n")
        )
```

type mismatch Error:
 found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[String,_$2]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]

My url splits json data stream - it is not a twitter stream

Please explain to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you want to get from the response. `stream()` returns a `Future`, therefore if you `flatMap` on it, you need to also return a future from the handler. What exactly do you want to be returned there? For example, if you want to get `Future[String]` with the entire body of the response, you can use `runReduce(_ + _)`:

```
val result: Future[String] = ws.url(url).stream()
    .flatMap(response => response.body
      .via(framing)
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(_ + "\n")
      .runReduce(_ + _)
    )
```

`runReduce(f: (U, U) => U)` returns a `Future[U]`, that is, in your case it would be `Future[String]`. If you want to handle each element of the incoming stream separately by some other function, you can use `runForeach`:

```
ws.url(url).stream()
    .flatMap( response => response.body
      .via(framing)
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(_ + "\n")
      .runForeach(s => handleString(s))
    )
```

Without more specifics about what you want to do, it is hard to provide a more concrete answer.

---

**Update:** if you want to throttle messages coming from the external server, you can use the built-in [`throttle`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#throttle(elements:Int,per:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maximumBurst:Int,mode:akka.stream.ThrottleMode):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]) combinator:

```
val result: Future[Source[String, _]] = ws.url(url)
  .stream()
  .map { response =>
    response.body
      .via(framing)
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(_ + "\n")
      .throttle(10, 1.second, 10, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
  }
```

Here, the `result` future will contain a stream of `String`s, which, when materialized, will produce at most 10 elements per second, backpressuring when necessary. You can find more in the documentation I linked to above.

Comment: Thank you - the out put is a json string. i want to get the string and to phrase it in scala and update my case class.

Comment: @SakarSR, I still don't understand, sorry. What do you mean by "phrase it"? Consider writing an example of what you want to do without reactive streams.

Comment: username: @Vladimir The url web server  emits json data continuously without any stop. I want to capture the data and do some computation on the data and pass it to the front-end. I also want to slow my web server (backpress) it. Planning to use Akka stream.    i hope its clear.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you want to pass the data from the external web service to the client of your own web service in a streaming fashion? That is, for example, the client of your service connects to it via a websocket?

Comment: @Vladimr Yes exactly that is what i want. I used a streaming timer through a websocket and its works fine. But in this case i do  not have any control on the external web service, Once i call the external web service it just starts to push some json data. I want to take control of this.

Comment: Not exactly sure what do you mean by "taking control". If you just want to backpressure the entire stream from the web service to the client, you don't really need to do anything special, since akka-streams does it automatically. If you want to *throttle* the stream, e.g. limiting the amount of elements passed each second, you can use [throttling combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423623/how-do-you-throttle-flow-in-the-latest-akka-2-4-6) for that. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes i want to do a throttling combination. Please can you show some code example to do it.

Comment: Added an example of throttling.